# unable to access any. onion sites

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, attacks

I've been unable to connect to any .onion sites for 5 days. I get onto tor okay and able to use Duck Duck Go but just can't access any .onion URLS. I've tried it on 4 different devices and two different internet connections. I received a message from the Tor Project on my PC yesterday that said I was blocked to prevent a DDOS attack.  not only do I have no idea how to create such an attack, but would never attempt such a thing. Am I blocked? How do I get unblocked. Please: give me a hand here.  O appreciate: any advice I can get. Thanks!

Comment: Can you access this hidden service: http://idnxcnkne4qt76tg.onion/ It is the homepage of the Tor project.

Comment: The question saw no activity since January and it is unlikely that it changes. So I close the question.